# Flutter: SearchDelegate Stream is empty when pressing Search

Tags: android, flutter, stream

I‘m using a `Stream` with `SearchDelegate`.
When I enter something in the search field, it's working fine. But as soon as I press the search symbol, it displays nothing, because the stream is empty. How is that possible?

Here is some code:

```
List<Notes> notes;

...

void search() {
   showSearch(
     context: context,
     delegate: Search(
         Stream.value(UnmodifiableListView<Note>(notes)).asBroadcastStream()
     )
}


class Search extends SearchDelegate{

   final Stream<UnmodifiableListView<Note>> notes;

   Search(this.notes);

   ...

   @override
   Widget buildResults(BuildContext context){
      return _buildStreamBuilder();
   }


   @override
   Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context){
      return _buildStreamBuilder();
   }


   StreamBuilder<UnmodifiableListView<Note>> _buildStreamBuilder() {
     return StreamBuilder< UnmodifiableListView<Note>> (
       stream: notes
       builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot< UnmodifiableListView<Note>>) {
          final results = snapshot.data.where((note){
              ....
   }
}
```

Why is the stream empty, when `buildResults()` is called, but not when `buildSuggestions()` is called?

Comment: you need to use showResults method https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SearchDelegate/showResults.html

Answer (score 1):

**Edit in the abstract class SearchDelegate:**

```
void showResults(BuildContext context) {
    _focusNode?.unfocus();
    _currentBody = _SearchBody.results;
 }
```

**Replace**:

```
void showResults(BuildContext context) {
    if(_queryTextController.text.isNotEmpty) {
      _focusNode?.unfocus();
      _currentBody = _SearchBody.results;
    }else{
      _focusNode?.unfocus();
    }
  }
```

It worked for me